# How to replace HTML tag with js script during DOM creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to solve an issue.
I have a CMS and I'm using CKEditor to create my HTML with a WYSIWYG editor.

I want to insert in my HTML some components (javascript): CKeditor of course cannot manage these components so I create a plugin to create a placeholder.

The result is an HTML like this:

```
<p>sample text</p>
<p><widget data_id="2" data_type="gallery"></widget></p>
<p>sample text</p>
```

Now I need to replace during page load the `<widget>` tag with my widget. 
I have some api to call so I can return for a gallery the images or the html snippet.

I don't want to use iFrame, I think to use vuejs to render my components but I never use it. Any other idea? Ajax?

Comment: i bet you have typo in attribute names: `data_id`->`data-id`

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317043/bad-review-queue-audit?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(document).onload(function(){

//Type code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  var widgets = document.querySelectorAll(`widget`);

  for( index=0; index < widgets.length; index++ ) {
    
    var id = widgets[index].getAttribute("data_id");

    switch (widgets[index].getAttribute("data_type")) {

      case "gallery":
        // make a httprequest (ajax), read a json file, ...
        widgets[index].innerHTML = "your gallery id: " + id;
        break;

      case "notes":
        // make a httprequest (ajax), read a json file, ...
        widgets[index].innerHTML = "your notes id: " + id;
        break;

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<p>sample text</p>
<p><widget data_id="2" data_type="gallery"></widget></p>
<p>sample text</p>
<p><widget data_id="3" data_type="notes"></widget></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When page loads you can do something like the following with ajax

```
$(function() {
  $('widget').each(function() {
    var $widget = $(this),
      widgetData = {
        id: $widget.attr('data_id'),
        type: $widget.attr('data_type')
      };   

    $.get(url, widgetData, function(response) {
      var $newElement = $(response)
      $widget.replaceWith($newELement);
      // run any script associated with widget
      $newElement.doSomething();
    });
  });
});
```

If the widgets don't involve any html being returned you could also use `$.getScript()`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have client-side widgets (widget make itself ajax request for data if need):

```
var widgets = {
    gallery: function(id)
    {
        ...
        return content;
    },
    ......
}
```

Then calling this on document ready will replace placeholders (`<widget data-id="2" data-type="gallery"></widget>`) with widgets:

```
$(function(){
    $.each('widget'), function () {
        var jq = $(this);
        var opts = jq.data();
        jq.replaceWith(new widgets[opts.type](opts.id));
    });
});
```